# SQL SUM of one tables based on two values

Tags: sql

If possible some help with the following question. I need to make a margin analyses. This I can do with one table and in the table both Cost as Turnover are mentioned. Via the ordernumber I would like to connect the cost and turnover of one ordernumber.

**Via this query I get the Turnover(omzet)**

```
select  GBK.bkstnr_sub as Ordernummer,
        SUM(GBK.bdr_hfl*-1) as Omzet
from [040].dbo.gbkmut as GBK with (nolock)
where  (GBK.dagbknr = 50 or GBK.dagbknr = 40)and (GBK.reknr BETWEEN '     8000' AND '     8980') 
and GBK.bkstnr_sub in (Select ORK.ordernr from [040].dbo.orkrg as ORK with (nolock)  

where ORK.ord_soort = 'V' and ORK.status = 'A' and YEAR(ork.orddat)= '2014')

GROUP BY GBK.bkstnr_sub
```

**Via this query I get the cost(kostprijs)**

```
select  GBK.bkstnr_sub as Ordernummer,
        SUM(GBK.bdr_hfl*-1) as Omzet

from [040].dbo.gbkmut as GBK with (nolock)

where  (GBK.dagbknr = 50 or GBK.dagbknr = 40)and (GBK.reknr BETWEEN '     7000' AND '     8980') 
and GBK.bkstnr_sub in (Select ORK.ordernr from [040].dbo.orkrg as ORK with (nolock)  

where ORK.ord_soort = 'V' and ORK.status = 'A' and YEAR(ork.orddat)= '2014')

GROUP BY GBK.bkstnr_sub
```

My wished result are the following columns; Ordernumber, Turnover, cost

Please give direction. At the moment I am lost.

Comment: Review [this article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)  using venn diagrams to describe how joins work.  If you treat each of your queries as a inline view (read as a table) and join them together, you can get your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a join here, this should give you what you want:

```
select  bkstnr_sub as Ordernummer,
        SUM(case when reknr BETWEEN '     8000' AND '     8980'  then GBK.bdr_hfl * -1 end) as Omzet,
        SUM(case when reknr BETWEEN '     7000' AND '     8980'  then GBK.bdr_hfl * -1 end) as kostprijs
from    [040].dbo.gbkmut
where   (dagbknr = 50 or dagbknr = 40) and 
        bkstnr_sub in (
            Select ordernr 
            from [040].dbo.orkrg
            where ord_soort = 'V' and 
                  status = 'A' and 
                  YEAR(orddat)= '2014')
GROUP BY bkstnr_sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to combine the results and avoid the sub queries.  I've not given it the needed thought.  This is the simplest approach that is easy to understand; without rewriting both queries.

```
SELECT Turnover.OrderNummer, 
   TurnOver.omzet as TurnoverOmzet, 
   Cost.Omzet as CostOmzet
FROM 
    (SELECT GBK.bkstnr_sub as Ordernummer,
            SUM(GBK.bdr_hfl*-1) as Omzet
     FROM [040].dbo.gbkmut as GBK with (nolock)
     WHERE (GBK.dagbknr = 50 or GBK.dagbknr = 40)
       and (GBK.reknr BETWEEN '     8000' AND '     8980') 
       and GBK.bkstnr_sub in 
          (SELECT ORK.ordernr 
           FROM  [040].dbo.orkrg as ORK with (nolock)  
           WHERE ORK.ord_soort = 'V' 
             and ORK.status = 'A' 
             and YEAR(ork.orddat)= '2014')
     GROUP BY GBK.bkstnr_sub) as turnover
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT GBK.bkstnr_sub as Ordernummer,
            SUM(GBK.bdr_hfl*-1) as Omzet
     FROM [040].dbo.gbkmut as GBK with (nolock)
     WHERE (GBK.dagbknr = 50 or GBK.dagbknr = 40)
       and (GBK.reknr BETWEEN '     7000' AND '     8980') 
       and GBK.bkstnr_sub in 
       (SELECT ORK.ordernr 
        FROM  [040].dbo.orkrg as ORK with (nolock)  
        WHERE ORK.ord_soort = 'V' 
          and ORK.status = 'A' 
          and YEAR(ork.orddat)= '2014')
     GROUP BY GBK.bkstnr_sub) as Cost
ON Turnover.orderNummer = Cost.orderNummer
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping. Suddenly I had a other thougt and used the code below.

```
select  GBK.bkstnr_sub as Ordernummer,
        SUM(GBK.bdr_hfl*-1) as Omzet,
        SUM(GBKK.bdr_hfl) as Kostprijs

from [040].dbo.gbkmut as GBK with (nolock)

 JOIN 

             (select    GBKK.bkstnr_sub,    
                    GBKK.bdr_hfl

            from [040].dbo.gbkmut as GBKK with (nolock)
            where  (GBKK.dagbknr = 50 or GBKK.dagbknr = 40)and GBKK.reknr BETWEEN '     7000' AND '     7980'
            and GBKK.bkstnr_sub in (Select ORK.ordernr from [040].dbo.orkrg as ORK with (nolock)  

            where ORK.ord_soort = 'V' and ORK.status = 'A' and YEAR(ork.orddat)= '2014')) as GBKK
on GBK.bkstnr_sub = GBKK.bkstnr_sub
```